# How do I get VSCode intellisense to recognize a Polymorphic Function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a function that can accept a single number or an array of numbers and return back either a single result or an array of results.  I cannot get VScode to return the proper type into the stored variable for intellisense.

I've already tried using some documentation patterns with JSDoc like the following:

```js
/**
 * Some Description
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {number} nums
 * @returns {number}
 *//**
 * Some other Description for array version!
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @returns {number[]}
 */
```

I have also tried the following but to no avail:

```js
/**
 * Some Description
 * @param {number|number[]} nums
 * @returns {number|number[]}
 */
```

This approach says that the variable can be either or and doesn't actually give a definite result.

```js
/**
 * Some Description
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {number} nums
 * @returns {number}
 *//**
 * Some other Description for array version!
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @returns {number[]}
 */
function addOne(nums) {
   if (Array.isArray(nums))
      return nums.map(n => n+1);
   else
      return nums + 1;
}

var a = addOne(1); // ::number -> Intellisense shows a is of type number CORRECT!

var b = addOne([ 1, 2 ]); // ::number -> Intellisense shows b as if it's of type number which is incorrect.  It should be ::number[] which would be correct.
```

Basically, it should show `var a;` from the above example as type `::number` and `var b;` as type `::number[]`

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome to Stack! What about only accepting and returning arrays? Treat all potential arrays as always being arrays, even if they have a length of 1. On the other hand, using `nums.map(addOne)` it is clear what procedure is being done to the array. Or what about having 2 functions? I don't think jsdoc will be able to infer the types as you want it to as it won't be running the function to determine what it did.

Comment: Hey @GrahamPHeath thanks for the comment.  I actually used your approach for now in my code!  Would really be nice if there was a way to do this though for convenience as well as being explicit about it.